# python3 arrow keypress return the value

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I want to add a method to a class that returns me the next arrow key that is pressed. Why does my code not work?

```
    def returnKeyEntry(self):
      while True:
        press = pygame.key.get_pressed()        
        if press[K_UP]:
          return "up"
          break
        if press[K_DOWN]:
          return "down"
          break
        if press[K_RIGHT]:
          return "right"
          break
        if press[K_LEFT]: 
          return "left"
          break
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Are you seeing unexpected results? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Nothing happens and the program get stuck in the loop :(

Comment: at least remove `while True`. You should have only one infinite loop - the mainloop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because it is an infinite loop that does not run any PyGame event code. Without its event queue being run, Pygame's keyboard state that you're querying doesn't get updated. So, if no arrow keys are being pressed at the very moment you call the function, it will always loop forever (regardless of what gets pressed later).

If you're not using the rest of the Pygame Event queue, you can still let it handle its internal stuff by calling [`pygame.event.pump`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) once per frame. If you did that just before you assign `press`, the rest of the code you've shown should return when an arrow key is pressed (the `break` statements are all unnecessary after `return`, but that's harmless). Note, however, that nothing will be happening in the background while you're waiting for an arrow key to be pressed (which may not be what you had in mind).

A better approach would be to integrate your input handling into an existing loop elsewhere in your code. I can't really offer concrete suggestions about how to do that without knowing more about your project and how it is organized.